# How would telepathy among kinsmen effect preindustrial societies?

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, economy

So if people from the same family can communicate telepathically over long distances, how would that effect postindustrial societies? Ie rome, medieval times or even early modern times

The way it would/ might work is the more blood you have in common the further you could communicate, ie two siblings could communicate over vast distances since they have the same blood, but a parent and child would communicate over half that since the child only has half the blood of the parent.

I am thinking that nepotism would be through the roof. It was already super big back in old times, but it now has the added benefit of communication. Maybe more equality for women since if you station all your sons far away and need more people to communicate with you would have to use daughters. I don't think that it would lead to more population since people back then were already trying to have large numbers of kids.

I do not know if empires would be easier to maintain since although you could get word of uprisings and revolts, there are no fast methods of travel to send armies and the like.

I think that famines would be more likely avoided since merchants could be able to know the price of grain/ food around the world and know where to sell food for higher prices, but then again if there is no advancement in food production, there would still be no food to eat.

I think there would be less brigands and outlaws since if you were robbed you could make it known to lots of people and then they would show up, maybe not when you got robbed, but they would patrol around that area.

Maybe a rise in inbreeding since if you want to communicate further, you need more blood/ in common? But then again I read somewhere that pre modern people were used to inbreed all the time by marrying their cousins

Is there anything major im missing or did I get anything wrong?
Thanks

Comment: A few questions that might help people answer: (1) how wide does “kinsmen” go? Brothers and sisters? First cousins? Second? (2) is it blood or magical (ex: does my spouse gain telepathy with me? (3) how deep does “kinsman” go? Do my grandparents have it? Do my grandchildren have it? (4) Do all of my “kin” benefit, or is this like a dominant gene where sometimes the trait passes over someone?

Comment: Could you explain what makes you believe that in the presence of such a great difference from the real world, history would progress along the same path? Why would there be any society similar to ancient Rome (whatever you think that is -- the history of "ancient Rome" spans a millennium, and the society changed dramatically during that time), or anything *remotely* resembling medieval western Europe? P.S. "Effect" with an ee and "affect" with an aye are different words with different meanings.

Comment: Yeah i gave that as an example of the technology level, not meaning literal Republican Rome or imperial or what not

Comment: More questions: how good is this telepathy? Is it just all 5 senses (or less)? Or do I also pick up my kinfolks impressions of the situation. If one of my kin attends an economics course while I attend a physics lecture, do we both walk away with the education?

Comment: Is it impossible to deceive over telepathy? For example, if so am the King of England and my brother is King of France, would it be impossible fo him to hide his intent to cross the channel and invade, or could he offer telepathic assurances of fealty while planning the invasion with his generals?

Comment: This is a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-please-develop-my-high-concept-questions). There cannot be one single way society and the world would change. This can take any sort of direction. Just look at how many different societies we've had and how they've dealt with the same things in vastly different ways, even if all have ultimately the same capabilities: the Chinese, Egyptians, Romans, Norse, Aztec, etc. Different governmental structures, different technological advances, different approaches to war, diplomacy, etc.

Comment: Also siblings on average share (roughly) 50% kinship, same as parent-child. Because just like on average you only get half your genes from a specific parent, also, on average, whatever gene you consider, there's a 50/50 chance your sibling got that gene from the same parent (hence identical) or the other parent (hence no statistical.connection at all).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like it would enforce any sort of nobility based system, as a more effective method of communication inherently means a more effective government, meaning that the basis for nobility wouldn't be a culture in a vacuum of psudoscientfical principles of superiority but rather how closely you could communicate with other governmental officials, meaning that presuming a nobility based system already exists, anybody with relation to the family at the question would genuinely be at a genuine intrinsic advantage with regards to governing, unlike real life where the advantage is entirely societal.(Edit: This was written at 11 at night when I really should have been asleep and now I'm regretting it)

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at the old model your replacing. The king, or chief, or tyrant rules nothing outside of his immediate surroundings. He can only directly command the men within earshot. And can only project that power (by marching the army) a short distance. The far lands are ungoverned (at least by the tyrant himself).

The way monarchies and empires dealt with this impossible situation was securing promises of fealty from remote warlords, securing this loyalty with hostages (spouses, parents, beloved siblings, children) and whenever possible replacing the remote warlord with someone who has proven their loyalty by bribes and faithful service.

You can send an order by messenger, but there’s no guarantee your written word is properly understood. Getting clarity can take days of back and forth. Even a faithful vassal can badly misunderstand direction. So, ultimately, the Empire is always much more frail than it looks.

Telepathy allows live two-way communication between vassal and lord. Concerns from the vassal about things I might not have considered (like the people are starving and can’t afford double taxes) can swiftly be brought to my attention.

Practically, my personal reach extends from earshot to several days’ ride (a days ride being about 30 miles, so a few hundred miles). Large empires become possible for every chief without having to cultivate as deep an administrative infrastructure. However, those who do invest in networks of professional representatives of the King can create truly impressive-reaching Empires.

If telepathy is more than word, but also sight and sound, I can quickly glean the actual situation (like observing that there’s a cholera outbreak in the northern territories), without my vassals necessarily needing to have the necessary skill.

In this case, I might want to keep many experts within earshot of someone on this network. Family members can describe what they see and hear to the experts, who can conduct research remotely through our network. In this case I might want to station several family members ear these experts, or train family to be experts themselves.

Sight and sound telepathy provides some anti-corruption. I will be able to tell how swiftly my sibling is delivering my messages, and whether they are delivering my messages accurately.

Which says nothing about stability. If the people are corrupt, and your messengers can lie over telepathy, Empires will still fall.

If, however, telepathy is lie-proof, you now have an incredible incentive to place your relatives in those tyrant positions. Previously, you might not have wanted to do this so that your message network can move. But now, telepathy also brings stability.

With lie proof telepathy, my personal reach now extends to the limit of my family network (because we are all trustworthy with one another). So not just my reach, but my far-deployed brother, plus his less far deployed children, and so on.